# Where can I use the b element in HTML5

Tags: html, icons

I know that the semantic way of the b element on HTML5 has changed, so it should no longer be bold.

Is it ok to use the b element for example to style icons / arrows or the three dots "..." on an pagination (e.g. << 1 2 ... 5 6 >>).

I like the  tag cause its short. Would it be the correct way to use it like that or how else would I style these little things (Pagination dots / icons) as described above. Would i at best use a span element with a specific class on it?

Thank you.

Marv

Comment: This question calls for opinions on interpretations of vague (and varying) descriptions in work-in-progress drafts. Moreover, it incorrectly describes “it should no longer be bold”; on the contrary, HTML5 drafts specify that the expected rendering of `b` is bold text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, the B element hasn't been removed nor made deprecated. It has been changed from a styling tag (*bold*) to a "semantic" tag.

Frow [the w3.org](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags) :

> You should not use b and i tags if there is a more descriptive and
>   relevant tag available. If you do use them, it is usually better to
>   add class attributes that describe the intended meaning of the markup,
>   so that you can distinguish one use from another.
>
> The b element represents a span of text to be stylistically offset
>   from the normal prose without conveying any extra importance, such as
>   key words in a document abstract, product names in a review, or other
>   spans of text whose typical typographic presentation is boldened.

Navigation arrows aren't "normal prose" and not really "text". Using a B element to style navigation arrows is wrong. You should use CSS to style them.

Comment: Non sequitur. “Stylistically offset” is a vague expression, and there is no logical way to infer from it that the element must not be used in the case described in the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What's not clear in "normal prose" ?

Comment: “normal” and “prose”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Can you say with a straight face that a navigation arrow is "normal prose" ?

Comment: An arrow is not “normal prose” for most definitions of “normal” and “prose”, so why couldn’t you offset an arrow from normal prose? And “wrong” is a strong word when there are no tangible objective criteria for correctness.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela would you mind elaborating on your comments and clarifying them a bit? I read them and I have no idea what you're talking about.